# About the code section of PE format

Tags: portable-executable

1. Is it true that entry-point always belongs to code section?
2. Is the code section consecutive or divided into several blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Yes** the entry-point always belongs to the code section.
2. Code section **CAN** be divided into several blocks.

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985992.aspx) article for more information.

Answer (score 2):

AND the code section can have any name! The code section is typically named '.text', but it can be named 'UPX' (when compressed with upx) or it could be named '+s8%4x' or 'data' or even have no name at all!!